# How can I test a new disk before production use?

Tags: hard-drive

Does anyone have a good way to test a disk before production use? I will be getting two new drives from Newegg and would like to test them before making a RAID array.

Would a (long) format be sufficient enough to find any surprises? I've seen a lot of drives in user reviews that died a week after their first use.

I found a post on Super User that recommended SpinRite, but I would prefer something free.

Comment: What brand drives?

Comment: Look at crystaldiskinfo. Can give decent stats on your hdds health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like [Hitachi Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hitachigst.com/support/downloads/?linkto=QL) - it is a bootable CD which can perform full HDD diagnostics and many tests. I think it could also work with other HDD brands than Hitachi.

[image]

Comment: Great, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

It a bit depends what You want to test ;)

Try HDD Regenerator (from Hirens Boot CD) for surface testing, error searching.
For fast scan or temperature info, speed I recomend HD Tune.